# Extract All Lowest Address

Tags: sql, ssis

I am trying to extract all the address number values from the example table below except the lowest addressnumber for each group.  They need to be grouped first by the accountnumber. **The table below is the result of primary result set** so I need a subquery or cte or something.  How can this be accomplished.  Cursor?

```
addressnumber   accountnumber
3               15847
4               15847
5               15847
6               15847
8               15847
3               4310
4               4310
3               4350
4               4350
6               4350
3               5076
4               5076

SELECT
       addressnumber,
       a.accountnumber [accountnumber],
       a.accountid accountid,
       a.accountratingcode [accountsegment],
       a.address1_addresstypecode,
       a.address1_city,
       a.address1_country,
       a.address1_line1,
       a.address1_line2,
       a.address1_line3,
       a.address1_postalcode,
       a.address1_stateorprovince,
       a.address2_city,
       a.address2_country,
       a.address2_line1,
       a.address2_line2,
       a.address2_line3,
       a.address2_postalcode,
       a.address2_stateorprovince,
       a.creditlimit,
       a.creditonhold,
       a.customertypecode,
       a.industrycode,
       a.name [name],
       a.ownerid,
       a.parentaccountid,
       a.paymenttermscode,
       a.sik_billingemail,
       a.sik_billingfax,
       a.sik_billingphone,
       a.sik_copyprimaryadd,
       a.sik_deliverymethodid,
       a.sik_warehouseid,
       a.telephone1 [main phone],
       ca.customeraddressid,
       ca.addressnumber,
       ca.city ca_city,
       ca.country ca_country,
       ca.line1 ca_line1,
       ca.line2 ca_line2,
       ca.line3 ca_line3,
       ca.postalcode ca_postalcode,
       ca.sik_addressemail ca_email,
       ca.sik_scribeexternalid [ca_location_id],
       ca.stateorprovince ca_state,
       ca.telephone1 ca_telephone,
       dm.sik_methodid,
       osm.localizedlabel [address type],
       pa.name [parentaccountname],
       w.sik_code [warehouse code],
       w.sik_name [warehouse name]

FROM account a
LEFT JOIN account pa ON a.parentaccountid = pa.accountid
JOIN customeraddress ca ON a.accountid = ca.parentid
JOIN optionsetmetadata osm ON osm.entityname = 'customeraddress'
    AND osm.optionsetname = 'addresstypecode'
    AND ca.addresstypecode = osm.[option]
LEFT JOIN sik_warehouse w ON a.sik_warehouseid = w.sik_warehouseid
LEFT JOIN sik_deliverymethods dm ON a.sik_deliverymethodid = dm.sik_deliverymethodsid

WHERE a.accountnumber IN ('002-100455','58398',
    '4350',
    '5076',
    '4310',
    '15847')
    AND addresstypecode = 2
    AND ca.jms_status = 100000000

ORDER BY [accountnumber],
         ca.addressnumber ASC
```

Comment: Ok that sounds like a good start, then how would I fit that into the primary query that I just added to the original?

Comment: If using row_number.  Make your primary query a cte and add column for rownumber. then select * from cte where rn>1. I reread and saw you want all but the first in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by accountnumber order by addressnumber) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: i think you want seqnum = 1. Currently this will return everything but the lowest address value for each group

Comment: @KeithL . . . That would be more typical, but the question says:  "I am trying to extract all the address number values from the example table below except the lowest addressnumber for each group. "

Comment: oops. I guess i read it wrong. It's more typical to just get the "latest" or "first"

Comment: Had it right ...seqnum>1.  I want to filter out the first record.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from primaryresult as p
    left outer join (select min(addressnumber)
                           ,accountnumber
                     from primaryresult
                     group by accountnumber
                    ) as iq
        on p.result.account number = iq.accountnumber
            and p.addressnumber = iq.minaddress
where minaddess is null
```

Comment: Need to use the code block button when answering with code otherwise, just text is presented instead of a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final if you are interested:

```
 WITH shiptorows AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a1.accountnumber ORDER BY ca1.addressnumber ASC) rn,
               ca1.customeraddressid ca1id
        FROM customeraddress ca1
        JOIN account a1 ON ca1.parentid = a1.accountid
        WHERE a1.accountnumber IN ('002-100455', '58398',
            '4350',
            '5076',
            '4310',
            '15847')
            AND addresstypecode = 2
            AND ca1.jms_status = 100000000
    )
    SELECT shiptorows.rn,
           addressnumber,
           a.accountnumber [accountnumber],
           a.accountid accountid,
           a.accountratingcode [accountsegment],
           a.address1_addresstypecode,
           a.address1_city,
           a.address1_country,
           a.address1_line1,
           a.address1_line2,
           a.address1_line3,
           a.address1_postalcode,
           a.address1_stateorprovince,
           a.address2_city,
           a.address2_country,
           a.address2_line1,
           a.address2_line2,
           a.address2_line3,
           a.address2_postalcode,
           a.address2_stateorprovince,
           a.creditlimit,
           a.creditonhold,
           a.customertypecode,
           a.industrycode,
           a.name [name],
           a.ownerid,
           a.parentaccountid,
           a.paymenttermscode,
           a.sik_billingemail,
           a.sik_billingfax,
           a.sik_billingphone,
           a.sik_copyprimaryadd,
           a.sik_deliverymethodid,
           a.sik_warehouseid,
           a.telephone1 [main phone],
           ca.customeraddressid,
           ca.addressnumber,
           ca.city ca_city,
           ca.country ca_country,
           ca.line1 ca_line1,
           ca.line2 ca_line2,
           ca.line3 ca_line3,
           ca.postalcode ca_postalcode,
           ca.sik_addressemail ca_email,
           ca.sik_scribeexternalid [ca_location_id],
           ca.stateorprovince ca_state,
           ca.telephone1 ca_telephone,
           dm.sik_methodid,
           osm.localizedlabel [address type],
           pa.name [parentaccountname],
           w.sik_code [warehouse code],
           w.sik_name [warehouse name]

    FROM account a
    LEFT JOIN account pa ON a.parentaccountid = pa.accountid
    JOIN customeraddress ca ON a.accountid = ca.parentid
    JOIN optionsetmetadata osm ON osm.entityname = 'customeraddress'
        AND osm.optionsetname = 'addresstypecode'
        AND ca.addresstypecode = osm.[option]
    LEFT JOIN sik_warehouse w ON a.sik_warehouseid = w.sik_warehouseid
    LEFT JOIN sik_deliverymethods dm ON a.sik_deliverymethodid = dm.sik_deliverymethodsid
    JOIN shiptorows ON shiptorows.ca1id = ca.customeraddressid

    WHERE a.accountnumber IN ('002-100455', '58398',
        '4350',
        '5076',
        '4310',
        '15847')
        AND addresstypecode = 2
        AND ca.jms_status = 100000000
        AND rn > 1

    ORDER BY [accountnumber],
             ca.addressnumber ASC
```